# How to create my network using QuickGraph (c#)

Tags: c#, quickgraph

I have several nodes (undirected graph, bidirecional) ... Each two nodes have a distance...

1 - How can I create that network using QuickGraph?
2 - What is the right algorithm to calculate the best shortest path bettween two nodes (Considering that may pass in other nodes before, example : best path A->B, passing in C and D)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About shortest paths, see [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Shortest path from A to B, passing through X, is essentially a shortest path from A to X plus a shortest path from X to B. (Not "the" shortest path, as there may be several ones.)